# JMS QUEUE: how to store message in the queue until flag is set to true

Tags: java, jms, spring-jms

I was trying a sample application of JMS queue.. I want the message coming in the queue to stay there until my flag is set to true. I am using spring framework and an MDP Listener with following configuration:

Server-context.xml:

```
<bean id="MDPListener" class="controller.MDPListener"></bean>

<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL">
        <value>tcp://localhost:61616</value>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="dataQueue15"></constructor-arg>

</bean>

<bean id="container" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="MDPListener"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="dataQueue"/>
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>



</bean>
```

My onMessage has the following code:

```
public void onMessage(Message message,Session session) {        

        System.out.println("The session: "+session.toString());
        System.out.println("New Message arrived part2 .. Passing to Controller");

        Boolean g=false;

        if(g==true)
        {
            System.out.println("Data true..session committed!!");
        }
        else
        {

            System.out.println("in the queue");
            throw new RuntimeException("Saved");
        }
}
```

Now when an exception is thrown, the message stays back in the queue and the control goes back to the same listener which listens to the same message all over again and stops after sometime. This results in dead queue. I am unable to store that message. I want my listener to listen to the queue but not to the previous message but next one. Please help!

Comment: I believe that JMS queue is pretty bad place to store things. If you don't want your message to be delivered - just don't post it into the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMS doesn't work that way - you have to move the message to another queue in your code.

Or, with ActiveMQ, you can configure the redelivery policy to send the message to the DLQ faster (I believe the default is 6 retries).

Comment: thank god! Finally a simple and to the point answer! Hats OFF! :D Works for me now .. Redelivery policy was the key